# How to "push back" a line that was popped out using "read" in bash

Tags: bash, file

I am using the "while/read" syntax to read lines:

```
some_command|while read line
do
  if something then
    read line
  else
    // how do I "unread"?
  fi
done
```

I make an additional "read" call while inside the "while" loop itself.

Sometimes, I need to do an "unread"

How do I do this? I prefer not to save the line to be unread in another buffer (not very clean, and requires checking flags)

Comment: I don't believe you can do that in the shell.

Comment: What do you want to do with the unread output?
When the while-loop is finished all the data (read and unread) is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. However, you can maintain a flag that determines if you need to read a line:

```
recycle=false
some_command | while $recycle || read line
do
  if something then
    read line
    recycle=false
  else
    # how do I "unread"?
    recycle=true
  fi
done
```

Your logic is unclear, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Glenn, Thanks for the suggestion, but that syntax isn't working in bash.  I tried: "while [[ $recycle == 1 ]] || read line" (after also failing using syntax)

Comment: Nothing wrong with that syntax. The contents of `$recycle` is a command ("true" or "false")

Comment: Glenn, you are correct.  I had substituted "0" for "false".  I didn't realize that "true" and "false" are actually bash commands.